# Using matrix operations instead of FOR loop for boolean comparison of cell array to index value

Tags: arrays, matlab, performance, for-loop, optimization

I have a function that takes one vector as its input, uses another function to create a derivative vector from the input, and then compares the two vectors to produce its output vector. I currently have it working with a for loop as follows:

The original array, `nameVec`, is used as the input to the following functions:

```
% INPUT: nameVec = ''  'a'  'b'  'aa'  'ab'  'ba'  'aba'  'abb'
```

First, a function called `computeParentName` removes the last character from each array element of `nameVec` and produces this cell array:

```
% OUTPUT: parentNameVec = ''  ''  ''  'a'  'a'  'b'  'ab'  'ab
```

Next, the function `computeParentIndex` finds the indices of where each element in `parentNameVec` appears in `nameVec`:

```
function [parentIndexVec] = computeParentIndex(nameVec)
    parentNameVec = computeParentName(nameVec);
    [~,parentIndexVec] = ismember(parentNameVec, nameVec);
end    
% OUTPUT: parentIndexVec = 1     1     1     2     2     3     5     5
```

I am now trying to develop a function that essentially acts in reverse, as it takes `nameVec` and outputs a cell array, which contains at each index, an array of all indices in `parentNameVec` where the value is that of the output array's ('daughterIndexVec`) current index

```
function [daughterIndexVec] = computeDaughterIndex(nameVec)
    parentIndexVec = computeParentIndex(nameVec);
    for i=1:length(parentIndexVec)
        daughterIndexVec{i} = find(parentIndexVec==i); 
    end
end
% OUTPUT: daughterIndexVec = {[1,2,3] [4,5] [6] [] [7,8] [] [] []}
```

Is there a simpler (more efficient) way to accomplish this without use of `for` loops?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second output of `ismember` to get the locations of each value in `parentNameVec` in `nameVec`  and then use `accumarray` to group all indices which share the same index in `nameVec` together in a cell array.

```
[~, ind] = ismember(parentNameVec, nameVec);
daughterIndexVec = accumarray(ind(:), 1:numel(ind), [numel(ind) 1], @(x){x.'});
%   {[1,2,3] [4,5] [6] [] [7,8] [] [] []}
```

Comment: Thanks, again! Very useful functions that I'm learning here. Would the `accumarray` be faster than the for loop then (i.e. unlike `arrayfun` and `cellfun`)?

Comment: @teepee yes. `accumarray` is very fast. You can test the speed yourself using the `timeit` function

Comment: it looks good to me but I'm getting a weird error when I run it:
`Error using accumarray
When SUBS is a column vector, the third input SZ must be of the form [N 1].` I'm not sure what's wonky here...

Comment: @teepee Try the modification I just made.

Comment: works great! Thank you very much for the help (and education). It seems to work now.